# Java/Scala (deep) collections interoperability

Tags: java, scala

Could you please share your opinion on what is the most elegant and/or efficient way of converting a

```
java.util.HashMap[
    java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList[
        java.util.ArrayList[java.lang.Double]
    ]
]  
(all of the objects are from java.util or java.lang)
```

to

```
Map[ 
    String, Array[ 
        Array[Double]
    ]
] 
(all of the objects are from scala)
```

Thanks,
-A

Comment: Isn't this more a design problem? What's the semantics of this structure? Why do you want to convert the objects?

Comment: Actually I am reading this data from a json file through jackson json library (I tried sjson and lift-json both failed me). Jackson json doesn't have a scala api so I used java API to do the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method for doing this has changed from 2.7 to 2.8.  Retronym's method works well for 2.8.  For 2.7, you'd instead use `collections.jcl` like so:

```
object Example {
  import scala.collection.jcl

  // Build the example data structure
  val row1 = new java.util.ArrayList[Double]()
  val row2 = new java.util.ArrayList[Double]()
  val mat = new java.util.ArrayList[java.util.ArrayList[Double]]()
  row1.add(1.0) ; row1.add(2.0) ; row2.add(3.0) ; row2.add(4.0)
  mat.add(row1) ; mat.add(row2)
  val named = new java.util.HashMap[String,java.util.ArrayList[java.util.ArrayList[Double]]]
  named.put("matrix",mat)

  // This actually does the conversion
  def asScala(thing: java.util.HashMap[String,java.util.ArrayList[java.util.ArrayList[Double]]]) = {
    Map() ++ (new jcl.HashMap(thing)).map(kv => {
      ( kv._1 ,
        (new jcl.ArrayList(kv._2)).map(al => {
          (new jcl.ArrayList(al)).toArray
        }).toArray
      )
    })
  }
}
```

So, the general idea is this: from the outside in, wrap the Java collection in a Scala equivalent, then use map to wrap everything in the next level.  If you want to convert between Scala representations, do that on the way out (here, the `.toArray` at the ends).

And here you can see the example working:

```
scala> Example.named
res0: java.util.HashMap[String,java.util.ArrayList[java.util.ArrayList[Double]]] = {matrix=[[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]]}

scala> val sc = Example.asScala(Example.named)
sc: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Array[Array[Double]]] = Map(matrix -> Array([D@1ea817f, [D@dbd794))

scala> sc("matrix")(0)
res1: Array[Double] = Array(1.0, 2.0)

scala> sc("matrix")(1)
res2: Array[Double] = Array(3.0, 4.0)
```

Answer (score 13):

I'm not claiming that it's all that elegant, but it works. I use the conversions from `JavaConversions` explicitly rather than implicitly to allow type inference to help a little. `JavaConversions` is new in Scala 2.8.

```
import collection.JavaConversions._
import java.util.{ArrayList, HashMap}
import collection.mutable.Buffer

val javaMutable = new HashMap[String, ArrayList[ArrayList[Double]]]

val scalaMutable: collection.Map[String, Buffer[Buffer[Double]]] =
    asMap(javaMutable).mapValues(asBuffer(_).map(asBuffer(_)))

val scalaImmutable: Map[String, List[List[Double]]] =
    Map(asMap(javaMutable).mapValues(asBuffer(_).map(asBuffer(_).toList).toList).toSeq: _*)
```

**UPDATE**: Here is an alternative approach that uses implicits to apply a given set of conversions to an arbitrarily nested structure.

```
trait ==>>[A, B] extends (A => B) {
  def apply(a: A): B
}

object ==>> {
  def convert[A, B](a: A)(implicit a2b: A ==>> B): B = a

  // the default identity conversion
  implicit def Identity_==>>[A] = new (A ==>> A) {
    def apply(a: A) = a
  }

  // import whichever conversions you like from here:
  object Conversions {
    import java.util.{ArrayList, HashMap}
    import collection.mutable.Buffer
    import collection.JavaConversions._

    implicit def ArrayListToBuffer[T, U](implicit t2u: T ==>> U) = new (ArrayList[T] ==>> Buffer[U]) {
      def apply(a: ArrayList[T]) = asBuffer(a).map(t2u)
    }

    implicit def HashMapToMap[K, V, VV](implicit v2vv: V ==>> VV) = new (HashMap[K, V] ==>> collection.Map[K, VV]) {
      def apply(a: java.util.HashMap[K, V]) = asMap(a).mapValues(v2vv)
    }
  }
}

object test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    import java.util.{ArrayList, HashMap}
    import collection.mutable.Buffer

    // some java collections with different nesting
    val javaMutable1 = new HashMap[String, ArrayList[ArrayList[Double]]]
    val javaMutable2 = new HashMap[String, ArrayList[HashMap[String, ArrayList[ArrayList[Double]]]]]

    import ==>>.{convert, Conversions}
    // here comes the elegant part!
    import Conversions.{HashMapToMap, ArrayListToBuffer}
    val scala1 = convert(javaMutable1)
    val scala2 = convert(javaMutable2)

    // check the types to show that the conversion worked.
    scala1: collection.Map[String, Buffer[Buffer[Double]]]
    scala2: collection.Map[String, Buffer[collection.Map[String, Buffer[Buffer[Double]]]]]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

@retronym's answer is good if your collections are homogenous, but it didn't seem to work for me when I had a mixed collection. For example:

`val x = Map(5 -> Array(1, List(2, 7), 3), 6 -> Map(5 -> List(7, 8, 9)))`

To convert such a collection to java, you need to rely on runtime types because the type of `x` is not something that can be recursively converted to java at compile time. Here is a method that can handle converting mixed scala collections to java:

```
  def convert(x:Any):Any =
  {
    import collection.JavaConversions._
    import collection.JavaConverters._
    x match
    {   
      case x:List[_] => x.map{convert}.asJava
      case x:collection.mutable.ConcurrentMap[_, _] => x.mapValues(convert).asJava
      case x:collection.mutable.Map[_, _] => x.mapValues(convert).asJava
      case x:collection.immutable.Map[_, _] => x.mapValues(convert).asJava
      case x:collection.Map[_, _] => x.mapValues(convert).asJava
      case x:collection.mutable.Set[_] => x.map(convert).asJava
      case x:collection.mutable.Buffer[_] => x.map(convert).asJava
      case x:Iterable[_] => x.map(convert).asJava
      case x:Iterator[_] => x.map(convert).asJava
      case x:Array[_] => x.map(convert).toArray
      case _ => x
    }   
  }
```

A similar method can be written for converting from java to scala.

Note that the return type of this method is `Any`, so in order to use the value returned, you may have to perform a cast: `val y = convert(x).asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[Int, Any]]`.